# Interaction with Lotus Connections

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript, ibm-connections

I need to get the data from some lotus connection  site, for example user's status,  from  the other site. I try to setup a connection with lotus via java, e.g.

```
> server = "https://" + path + param + "&format=full";
> URL profiles_url = new URL(server);
> // Open the URL: throws exception if not found
> HttpURLConnection profiles_conn = HttpURLConnection)profiles_url.openConnection();
> profiles_conn.connect();
> // Process the Atom feed in the response content
> readResponse(profiles_url.openStream(),args[0]);
```

But I always get the Response:   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Please give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the authentication issue this way:

```
protected void doView(RenderRequest rRequest, RenderResponse rResponse) throws PortletException, IOException, UnavailableException {
try { 
rResponse.setContentType("text/html");          
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://xxx/activities/service/atom2/todos");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(150000);
        con.setReadTimeout(150000);
        writeCookies(con, rRequest);                        

        DO_SOMETHING (con.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}       


private String doesLTPATokenCookieExists(RenderRequest request) {
Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
for (int i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Cookie Name " + cookie[i].getName());
    if (cookie[i].getName().equals("LtpaToken"))
        return cookie[i].getValue();
}
return null;
}

public URLConnection writeCookies(URLConnection urlConn,
    RenderRequest request) {
String cookieString = "";
cookieString += "LtpaToken" + "=" + doesLTPATokenCookieExists(request) + "; ";
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);     
return urlConn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you're authenticating, which is crucial. As the 401 error implies, Connections isn't treating your request as being authenticated. You need a valid `Authenticator` instance in there, but your code snippet suggests you haven't got that going, correct?

(As an aside, the [Apache Abdera](http://abdera.apache.org) project is recommended when working with the Lotus Connections API).